# Building PHP with docker-compose up has problem with sudo

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, drupal, sudo

When I run `docker-compose up` on a Drupal site I work on I get the following output:

```
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                           0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 37B                                                                                                                                                            0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                              0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/wodby/drupal-php:7.3                                                                                                                                1.3s
 => CACHED [1/5] FROM docker.io/wodby/drupal-php:7.3@sha256:05bc175d426b59eea40fd855125b8c86836081e76493f683d8ad40da8f2008e3                                                                   0.0s
 => ERROR [2/5] RUN sudo apk add --no-cache   autoconf   bash   build-base   openssl   libssh2-dev                                                                                             0.3s
------
 > [2/5] RUN sudo apk add --no-cache   autoconf   bash   build-base   openssl   libssh2-dev:
#4 0.240
#4 0.240 We trust you have received the usual lecture from the local System
#4 0.240 Administrator. It usually boils down to these three things:
#4 0.240
#4 0.240     #1) Respect the privacy of others.
#4 0.240     #2) Think before you type.
#4 0.240     #3) With great power comes great responsibility.
#4 0.240
#4 0.240 sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper
#4 0.240 sudo: a password is required
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c sudo apk add --no-cache   autoconf   bash   build-base   openssl   libssh2-dev]: exit code: 1
ERROR: Service 'php' failed to build
```

I've been searching and can't find anything I understand that will fix it.

This is the docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "2"

services:
  mariadb:
    image: wodby/mariadb:10.1-2.3.3
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: drupal
      MYSQL_USER: drupal
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: drupal
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    volumes:
      #      - ./mariadb-init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d # Place init .sql file(s) here.
      - ./.persist/mysql:/var/lib/mysql:cached # I want to manage volumes manually.
    labels:
      - "traefik.backend=mariadb"
      - "traefik.port=3306"
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:localhost"

  php:
    # 2. Images without Drupal – wodby/drupal-php:[PHP_VERSION]-[STABILITY_TAG].
    #    image: wodby/drupal-php:7.1-2.4.3
    #    image: wodby/drupal-php:7.0-2.1.0
    #    image: wodby/drupal-php:5.6-2.1.0
    #    image: wodby/drupal-php:5.3-2.1.0
    build: ./build/php
    environment:
      DOCKER_LOCAL: 1
      PHP_SENDMAIL_PATH: /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -S mailhog:1025
      DB_HOST: mariadb
      DB_USER: drupal
      DB_PASSWORD: drupal
      DB_NAME: drupal
      DB_DRIVER: mysql
      PHP_XDEBUG: 1
      PHP_XDEBUG_DEFAULT_ENABLE: 1
      PHP_XDEBUG_REMOTE_CONNECT_BACK: 0 # This is needed to respect remote.host setting bellow
      PHP_XDEBUG_REMOTE_HOST: "10.254.254.254" # You will also need to 'sudo ifconfig lo0 alias 10.254.254.254'
      PHP_IDE_CONFIG: "serverName=localhost" # Needed for xdebug for drush commands.
      PHP_XDEBUG_REMOTE_AUTOSTART: 0
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
      - ./.persist/public:/var/www/html/docroot/sites/default/files
      - ./.persist/private:/private

  nginx:
    # wodby/drupal-nginx:[DRUPAL_VERSION]-[NGINX_VERSION]-[STABILITY_TAG].
    image: wodby/drupal-nginx:8-1.13-2.4.2
    #    image: wodby/drupal-nginx:7-1.10-2.1.0
    #    image: wodby/drupal-nginx:6-1.10-2.1.0
    depends_on:
      - php
    environment:
      NGINX_STATIC_CONTENT_OPEN_FILE_CACHE: "off"
      NGINX_ERROR_LOG_LEVEL: debug
      NGINX_BACKEND_HOST: php
      NGINX_SERVER_ROOT: /var/www/html/docroot
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
      - ./.persist/public:/var/www/html/docroot/sites/default/files
    labels:
      - "traefik.backend=nginx"
      - "traefik.port=80"
      - 'traefik.frontend.rule=HostRegexp:localhost,{subdomain:[a-z0-9-\\.]+}.localhost, {subdomain:[a-z0-9]+}.ngrok.io'

  #  varnish:
  #    image: wodby/drupal-varnish:4.1-2.1.0
  #    depends_on:
  #      - nginx
  #    environment:
  #      VARNISH_SECRET: secret
  #      VARNISH_BACKEND_HOST: nginx
  #      VARNISH_BACKEND_PORT: 80
  #    labels:
  #      - 'traefik.backend=varnish'
  #      - 'traefik.port=6081'
  #      - 'traefik.frontend.rule=Host:varnish.localhost'

  redis:
    image: wodby/redis:3.2-2.1.0

  #  pma:
  #    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
  #    environment:
  #      PMA_HOST: mariadb
  #      PMA_USER: drupal
  #      PMA_PASSWORD: drupal
  #      PHP_UPLOAD_MAX_FILESIZE: 1G
  #      PHP_MAX_INPUT_VARS: 1G
  #    labels:
  #      - 'traefik.backend=pma'
  #      - 'traefik.port=80'
  #      - 'traefik.frontend.rule=Host:pma.localhost'

  solr:
    ## wodby/drupal-solr:[DRUPAL_VERSION]-[SOLR_VERSION]-[STABILITY_TAG].
    image: wodby/drupal-solr:8-6.4-2.0.0
    ##    image: wodby/drupal-solr:8-6.3-2.0.0
    #    image: wodby/drupal-solr:8-5.5-2.0.0
    ##    image: wodby/drupal-solr:7-6.4-2.0.0
    ##    image: wodby/drupal-solr:7-6.3-2.0.0
    ##    image: wodby/drupal-solr:7-5.5-2.0.0
    environment:
      SOLR_HEAP: 1024m
    ports:
      - "8983:8983"
    volumes:
      - ./.persist/solr:/opt/solr/server/solr/core1:delegated
    labels:
      - "traefik.backend=solr"
      - "traefik.port=8983"
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:solr.local"

  mailhog:
    image: mailhog/mailhog
    labels:
      - "traefik.backend=mailhog"
      - "traefik.port=8025"
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:mailhog.localhost"

  #  node:
  #    image: node:7-alpine
  #    working_dir: /app
  #    labels:
  #      - 'traefik.backend=node'
  #      - 'traefik.port=3000'
  #      - 'traefik.frontend.rule=Host:front.localhost'
  #    expose:
  #      - "3000"
  #    volumes:
  #      - ./path/to/your/single-page-app:/app
  #    command: sh -c 'npm install && npm run start'

  #  memcached:
  #    image: wodby/memcached:1.4-2.0.0

  traefik:
    image: traefik:1.7
    command: -c /dev/null --web --docker --logLevel=INFO --defaultEntryPoints='https,http' --entryPoints='Name:https Address::443 TLS:/certs/local.crt,/certs/local.key' --entryPoints='Name:http Address::80'
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    #      - '8080:8080' # Dashboard
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - ./.persist/certs:/certs
```

I'm on MacOS Big Sur.

SO is asking me to provide more details as my question is mostly code, but I'm not sure what else to add. I've seen a few blog posts and SO answers that have one line solutions but no info on where to put it, so am at a bit of a loss as I don't really understand the problem.

Comment: You don't need `sudo` in Docker at all.  In line 2 of a Dockerfile you can probably just delete it; or you can manually specify `USER root` if you need to.

Comment: To build on what David said : the process in your containers are run as root, unless you specify otherwise. So `apk` will be run as root directly, not needing `sudo`

Comment: @DavidMaze where is Dockerfile? All I have is docker-compose.yml

Comment: @Faeeria unless I did something I didn't notice during installation of docker I doubt I specified otherwise. I'm setting up a brand new mac.

Comment: You should be looking for `./build/php/Dockerfile` (in the directory named by the `build:` directive).

Comment: Thanks @DavidMaze, that got me through to a different error. Hopefully it's a bit easier to solve.

Answer (score 0):

I have two suggestion for your docker compose:

- Never use root user for your docker image (security level) , so if you need to fix permission you can define a new user and grant some permission be better .
- your docker-compose version is 2 but the current version is  3   so the second version is deprecated and there are a lot of functionalities provided by the version 3 you can check it.

If you want a drupal application that working with docker compose version 3 thanks to check this link : [drupal-docker-compose-3](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-drupal-with-docker-compose)

Comment: There are a couple of less-common Docker options, especially around resource limits, that are only available in Compose file version 2 in non-Swarm mode.  If you need that, staying on version 2 is fine.  Unlike version 1, [version 2 is not deprecated](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-versioning/).